# Hibernate Session scope in JTA transactions vs Open-Session-In-View

Tags: java, hibernate, session, jta, open-session-in-view

Is it correct to say that using `JTA` Transactions with H`ibernate` contrasts using the `Open-Session-In-View` with regards to the session scope?
From what I've been able to gather the Session scope in the `JTA` Transactions is a transaction (mainly based on this [link](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/sessionsandtransactions#Transaction_demarcation_with_JTA)) while in the `Open-Session-In-View` pattern the session's scope is the requrest and you can have multiple transactions in it.

I'm asking, first to understand, and secondly to verify "Who" is responsible for the session handling when using `JTA`.
Currently, when using the `Open-Session-In-View`, I have a `HibernateUtil` class which handles opening, retrieving and closing of sessions (via `ThreadLocal<Session>`).
When I'll switch over to using `JTA` will `Hibernate` handle the above session actions? (as a derivative maybe of my calling userTransaction.begin,userTransaction.rollback)

BTW, I'm asking about `JTA` as I need to coordinate a transaction across `Hibernate` `JMS` and `EHCache` so this isn't a general best-practices "lets-use-JTA" question.

Ittai

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're using JTA then the JTA manager (usually EJB3 container) is responsible for transactions.

Typically, the same good old open-transaction-in-view model is used, however with `UserTransaction` and, say, a SWING client it's possible to have long-lasting transactions spanning multiple requests (though it's a bad practice in general).

> BTW, I'm asking about JTA as I need to coordinate a transaction across Hibernate JMS and EHCache so this isn't a general best-practices "lets-use-JTA" question.

Good luck. I found that external transaction manager (I've used Atomikos) + Spring worked better for my needs than JBoss.